# Unable to connect to AWS EC2 Instance via HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, networking, amazon-ec2, network-protocols

I could connect to my EC2 instance via ssh using private keys. However I'm unable to connect to public DNS/IP address of EC2 instance even though security instances are configured properly. 
[image]
Enabled "Allow everyone everywhere", but still unable to connect to my EC2 instance. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a web server running inside the ec2 instance configured to serve external http requests?

Comment: @Ashan 
Thank you, your response lead to solution. My bad, apache was not installed. But however, I had to configure a spring boot app, and so enabling 8080 port solved my issue.

Comment: Thats great to hear. I have updated answer for any future references for others.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a web server running inside the ec2 instance configured to serve external http requests.